# Partner Central rest api 401 unauthorized access

Tags: rest, api, powershell

I followed the Microsoft doc to get the billing profile of a customer.
With the auth [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/partner-center-authentication?tabs=powershell-app-only%2Cdotnet-partner-consent%2Cdotnet-csp-auth%2Cdotnet-cpv-auth) with the Powershell Code

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-PartnerCenter -Credential $credential -ServicePrincipal -TenantId '<TenantId>'
```

Copied the access token and produced a Postman Get request but still got an 401 unauthorized request

[image]

It could be from the security update of Microsoft , but the Auth documentation is from january so i think These are the steps to get access to the parner central 
https://www.microsoftpartnercommunity.com/t5/UK-Partner-Zone-Discussions/FY19-CSP-program-new-mandatory-security-requirements/td-p/6981

Or I don't have the right permissions as a user to get the billing profile.
I know it's one step that I oversee or that it's one thing that I did wrong but I can't see it

I am aware that there are some questions on stackoverflow about this issue. But Can't seem to find a solution there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to get the access token with this Powershell code:

```
    $appId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$appSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $appId, $appSecret
$token = New-PartnerAccessToken -Consent -Credential $credential -Resource https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com -ServicePrincipal

New-PartnerAccessToken -RefreshToken $token.RefreshToken -Resource https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com -Credential $credential -ServicePrincipal
```

Source and probably more explanation to this you can find here: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/partner-center-authentication?tabs=dotnet-app-only%2Cpowershell-partner-consent%2Cdotnet-csp-auth%2Cdotnet-cpv-auth#partner-consent)
If the link becomes invalid search for Partner Consent process for the Partner Center

Hope this one helps you out, this was what worked for me. Struggled a lot to find this out also.

Also make sure in your Azure AD app you select access token in the  `Authentication` Setting beneath `Implicit grant`. And to select , `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` beneath the suggested redirect URL's

Answer (score 0):

which token you tried to access the Partner center api. First you have to generate the token by registering app with Partner center.
You have to use client/application id, tenant id/domain name, client secret.
Use that token to access the partner center api.